# Default XML Element

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, annotations

I have the following class:

```
    private String larquivoid;
    private String oper;
    private String type;


    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = Settings.NUMERIC_FIELD_VALUE;
    }

    @XmlValue
    public String getLarquivoid() {
        return larquivoid;
    }

    public void setLarquivoid(String larquivoid) {
        this.larquivoid = larquivoid;
    }


    @XmlAttribute
    public String getOper() {
        return oper;
    }

    public void setOper(String oper) {
        this.oper = oper;
    }
```

type is an attribute that I don´t want to use in my xml request. This is giving the usual problem:If a class has @XmlElement property, it cannot have @XmlValue property.

How can I make my type just an attribute of this class?

Comment: perhaps @XmlTransient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What's Going Wrong?

By default an unmapped property is treated as if it is annotated with `@XmlElement`.  This is why you are seeing the error that you are seeing.

### How to Fix it?

**Excluding Less Than Half the Properties**

If you need to exclude less than half a classes properties then you can annotate them individually with `@XmlTransient`.

**Excluding More Than Half of the Properties**

If you need to exclude more than half of the properties then I suggesting annotating your class with `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)`.  This will cause only annotated properties to be treated as mapped.